# Attempting to get aspect annotation recognized by eclipse luna while using m2e (maven) build

Tags: java, eclipse, m2eclipse, aspectj-maven-plugin

I'd like to start using Aspects within my Java code and found a RetryOnFailure annotation that I decided would be my first one.  At first my POM file showed an error, but through some research it seems that m2e in eclipse doesn't know when to run/build so I had to add a lifecycleMappingMetadata to my POM that got me past that.  However I still get an error in the class file on the Annotation within Eclipse.  Any idea how to get past that would be greatly appreciated.

Relevant piece of class file:

```
    @RetryOnFailure(attempts = 2, delay = 10, verbose = false)
private static LeadQualificationResponse callLeadQualificaiton(LeadQualificationRequest leadQualificationRequest, MidasStub midasStub) throws RemoteException {
    LeadQualificationResponse leadQualificationResponse = null;
    leadQualificationResponse = midasStub.leadQualification(leadQualificationRequest);
    return leadQualificationResponse;
}
```

Snippets of POM:

```
        <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jcabi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[0.8,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>ajc</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute>
                                        <runOnIncremental>false</runOnIncremental>
                                    </execute>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcabi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>ajc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

I've also tried to set the runOnIncremental to true and get the following error in the POM file on the execution element

### Execution default of goal com.jcabi:jcabi-maven-plugin:0.8:ajc failed: A required class was missing while executing com.jcabi:jcabi-maven-plugin:0.8:ajc: Lorg/sonatype/aether/RepositorySystemSession;

realm =    plugin>com.jcabi:jcabi-maven-plugin:0.8
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/com/jcabi/jcabi-maven-plugin/0.8/jcabi-maven-plugin-0.8.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/com/jcabi/jcabi-log/0.7.22/jcabi-log-0.7.22.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar
urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.7.3/aspectjrt-1.7.3.jar
urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/com/jcabi/jcabi-aether/0.7.22/jcabi-aether-0.7.22.jar
urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/kuali/maven/wagons/maven-s3-wagon/1.1.20/maven-s3-wagon-1.1.20.jar
urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/kuali/common/kuali-s3/1.0.1/kuali-s3-1.0.1.jar
urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.4.2/aws-java-sdk-1.4.2.jar
urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.1/httpclient-4.1.jar
urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1/httpcore-4.1.jar
urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.8/commons-codec-1.8.jar
urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.8.9/jackson-core-asl-1.8.9.jar
urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.8.9/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.9.jar
urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/3.1.2.RELEASE/spring-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/kuali/common/kuali-threads/1.0.9/kuali-threads-1.0.9.jar
urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.6.4/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.4.jar
urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.13.1/aether-util-1.13.1.jar
urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-connector-file/1.13.1/aether-connector-file-1.13.1.jar
urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-connector-asynchttpclient/1.13.1/aether-connector-asynchttpclient-1.13.1.jar
urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/com/ning/async-http-client/1.6.5/async-http-client-1.6.5.jar
urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/jboss/netty/netty/3.2.5.Final/netty-3.2.5.Final.jar
urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-connector-wagon/1.13.1/aether-connector-wagon-1.13.1.jar
urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/com/jcabi/jcabi-aspects/0.7.22/jcabi-aspects-0.7.22.jar
urls[25] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/com/jcabi/jcabi-maven-slf4j/0.7.22/jcabi-maven-slf4j-0.7.22.jar
urls[26] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjtools/1.7.3/aspectjtools-1.7.3.jar
urls[27] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
urls[28] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.0.1.Final/hibernate-validator-5.0.1.Final.jar
urls[29] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.1.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.1.GA.jar
urls[30] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/0.8.0/classmate-0.8.0.jar
urls[31] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/jfrog/maven/annomojo/maven-plugin-anno/1.4.1/maven-plugin-anno-1.4.1.jar
urls[32] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/2.3.0/sisu-inject-bean-2.3.0.jar
urls[33] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/3.1.0/sisu-guice-3.1.0-no_aop.jar
urls[34] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-bean-containers/2.3.0/guice-bean-containers-2.3.0.jar
urls[35] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-bean-inject/2.3.0/guice-bean-inject-2.3.0.jar
urls[36] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-plexus-shim/2.3.0/guice-plexus-shim-2.3.0.jar
urls[37] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar
urls[38] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/3.1.0/sisu-guice-3.1.0.jar
urls[39] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
urls[40] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-bean-reflect/2.3.0/guice-bean-reflect-2.3.0.jar
urls[41] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-bean-locators/2.3.0/guice-bean-locators-2.3.0.jar
urls[42] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-bean-binders/2.3.0/guice-bean-binders-2.3.0.jar
urls[43] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/1.0/cdi-api-1.0.jar
urls[44] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/jsr250-api/1.0/jsr250-api-1.0.jar
urls[45] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-bean-scanners/2.3.0/guice-bean-scanners-2.3.0.jar
urls[46] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-bean-converters/2.3.0/guice-bean-converters-2.3.0.jar
urls[47] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-plexus-metadata/2.3.0/guice-plexus-metadata-2.3.0.jar
urls[48] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-plexus-converters/2.3.0/guice-plexus-converters-2.3.0.jar
urls[49] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-plexus-locators/2.3.0/guice-plexus-locators-2.3.0.jar
urls[50] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-plexus-binders/2.3.0/guice-plexus-binders-2.3.0.jar
urls[51] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-plexus-scanners/2.3.0/guice-plexus-scanners-2.3.0.jar
urls[52] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-plexus-lifecycles/2.3.0/guice-plexus-lifecycles-2.3.0.jar
urls[53] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.0.6/plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar
urls[54] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
urls[55] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
urls[56] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
urls[57] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
urls[58] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guava/0.11.1/sisu-guava-0.11.1.jar
urls[59] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
urls[60] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar
urls[61] = file:/C:/Users/Jeffrey/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.1/commons-lang3-3.1.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

---

(com.jcabi:jcabi-maven-plugin:0.8:ajc:default:process-classes)

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem. 
Dont use version 0.8 of the jcabi-maven-plugin. Try with 0.9.2 instead. Seems to be resolved there.